# Illustrating Action Potential Conduction and Ion-Gated Channels

Tags: action-potential, peripheral-nervous-system, neuron

[image]

I can separately illustrate action potential and ion-gated channels along an axon.  However, I am not sure if I did the right thing on the picture below.  What I'm trying to show are the simultaneous processes of (1) the flow or propagation of action potential along the axon length, and (2) the position of ion-gated channels along the axon length.

The blue figures are for sodium. The red figures are for potassium. The arrows show the propagation of action potential.

Was I able to depict what I'm trying to show properly?  If not, how can I correct this?

Comment: For clarity - this is entirely your own diagram? Or you've modified someone else's?

Comment: @BryanKrause this is my own diagram.